# Laravel Image resize on uploaded file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, intervention

I'm using laravel intervention. When i try resize image on **uploaded** file like, it's return :

> Image source not readable

I can access image on http://laravel.test/laravel-filemanager/photos/sample.jpg from browser.

I've tried almost all ways. Like,

```
\Image::make(asset($data->image))->fit(300,300)->save()
```

or

```
\Image::make(public_path($data->image))->fit(300,300)->save()
```

or

```
\Image::make($data->image)->fit(300,300)->save()
```

I want to do, user select image from file manager, and i need to resize image. How i can do this?

Thank in advance

Comment: What's in `$data->image` ?

Comment: @apokryfos $data->image = 'laravel-filemanager/userName/sample.jpg'

Comment: `laravel-filemanager/userName/sample.jpg` seems inconsistent with the link `laravel-filemanager/photos/sample.jpg` (one is using the username and the other is just photos)

Comment: 'userName' or 'photos' is dynamic folder.  Even i was tried manuel writing file name.

Comment: try it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810373/laravel-5-6-image-intervention-upload-with-rename-and-resize

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
\Image::make(public_path('laravel-filemanager/photos/sample.jpg'))->fit(300, 300)->save(public_path('laravel-filemanager/photos/sample-resized.jpg'));
```

http://image.intervention.io/