# laravel 5.6 image intervention upload with rename and resize

Tags: laravel

**Step 1-Installation:** 
(composer require intervention/image)

**Step 2-Configuration:** 
After you have installed Intervention Image, open your Laravel config file config/app.php and add the following lines.

In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class

Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.

'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class

**Step 3-Uses:**
use Image

```
 public function avatar(Request $request){
    $user = new User();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if ($user->image){
            unlink(public_path('/image/user/').$user->image);
        }
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = $userName . "_profile_". $userId . "_" . $imageName;

        $directory = public_path('/image/user/');
        $imageUrl = $directory.$fileName;
        Image::make($image)->resize(200, 200)->save($imageUrl);
        $user->image = $fileName;
    }

    if ($user->save())
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Update successfully');

    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'There is an error message');
}
```

Comment: what error you found or what you kind of help you need. please mention in question properly.

Comment: what is your problem? do you need help or you want to share your code about how save image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step 2 is not needed if you are working on laravel 5.6 `composer require intervention/image` will install in your vendor folder and laravel package discovery will do the rest for you